# "The type is not generic, it cannot be be parameterized with arguments"

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to create a class implementing Blackberry's `Comparator` so I can easily sort 2D arrays.

```
import net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator;    

class ArrayComparator implements Comparator<Object[]> {
    ...
}
```

This gives me the error:

> The Type Comparator is not generic; it can not be parameterized with
>   arguments `<Object[]>`

This error goes away if I include the normal JRE library and import `java.util.Comparator`, but this won't compile because it is a mobile device, the library is not preverified, etc, etc, etc.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Remove the generic type argument `Object[]`. The compare method should take an `Object` argument which you'll need to cast.

Comment: ...don't attempt to use generic parameters?  Write an interface that is generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sicne you're defining a comparator for a particular class you don't need (and can't use) generics. Your array comparator should cast the `Object` type parameters to their corresponding type before comparing in the compare method you override.

For example, your ArrayComparator should cast `o1` and `o2` to an array. In the future if you make a, say, UserDataComparator the compare method should cast the parameters to your `UserData` class type.

FYI: Blackberry's compiler (RAPC) supports up to java 1.4 AFAIK (check [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1072/BlackBerry%20Java%20Development%20Environment%20Component%20Package%20Release%20Notes%20-%20build%20version.pdf)) so Generics, Enums and other Java 1.5 and above features are not supported.

**EDIT** As other persons pointed (and for the sake of a complete answer) I was not specific enough on my anwer. I have edited this answer to reflect some crucial points related to your issue.

Comment: In BlackBerry Java, you actually **cannot** use generics.  It's not that you don't **need** to use generics.  One of the other two answers should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Nate I was just pointing to the fact that he doesn't actually need generics for this case. Being able to use generics is a different matter, for I know it doesn't support generics as it also doesn't support, for example, enums. I should be more specific next time.

Answer (score 3):

net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator doesn't have Generic capabilities. You need to implement Comparator without any type information and compare all the items of the array. if the items of the array are objets, you need to implements the Comparator interface on this Objets too.

you can get more implementation information on this [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-a-Comparator-to-compare-objects/ta-p/445233)

Answer (score 3):

BlackBerry JRE is 1.3 (like CLDC 1.1) and don't support generics, non-synchronized collections and other things from modern java world.